# Dual hose portable AC unit creating negative air pressure

Tags: hvac

I bought a dual hose unit because it's supposed to not create negative air pressure in the room, but I can definitely feel the air resistance when I go to close the door to the room it is in. When the AC unit is off there's no resistance closing the door. Any idea why it would be creating negative air pressure?

Comment: think about what causes negative air pressure in a room ... then examine the AC unit closely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard that a lot of portable ACs are cheaply constructed and may have significant gaps in the construction of the — not sure what to call it, the condenser compartment, the hot side. Such gaps, if larger on the intake side of the blower than the outlet, will pull in more air than they leak out and produce a net negative pressure, like a single-hose unit but less so.

If you can find such gaps, sealing them up should lessen the negative pressure effect.

However, also remember that a door is a fairly large surface, and so a small pressure difference, multiplied by the area of the door, creates a lot of force on it. The amount of air moving may not be all that much; you've got a sensitive detector.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed the same thing with a dual-hose Whytner AC unit. It is in a small room with two airtight windows and one not-airtight-at-all door. When the unit is running, I can easily feel a strong flow of air from the hallway under the door. During the current hot spell (100F today), the inflow of warm air from the hallway prevents the room for cooling below 85F.